# Procedure/trigger SQL after inserting a row

Tags: sql, triggers, procedure

I'm not very keen in SQL. My plan is to create a trigger or a procedure in which a field of a table increments by 1 if I insert a row in another table.

For example: I create a row in Table1, so I increment +1 the field Table1Ocurrences in Table2.

The problem is that I don't know if the command AFTER INSERT is appliable in this case. Which sentences of code could I write? 
Thank you.

Comment: You should say which RDBMS you're using.

Comment: @Marc yes, some people believe that Microsoft SQL Server **is** SQL. in fact it is a misleading name for a DBMS.

Comment: Sorry. I'm using SQLite Manager.

Answer (score 1):

sure you can:

```
create trigger trigger_update
on table1
after insert
as 
begin
   ---do whatever you want
end
```

you can get the values from table1 inside your trigger by doing:

```
select * from INSERTED
```